# Including one page inside of another in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I know how to create view partials, but I want to show a certain action on a certain controller, like so:

```
RssController -> ShowRss 
/Rss/ShowRss
```

I want to show that page inside of this page:

```
MyBlog -> Index 
/MyBlog
```

What's the best way to do this, or am I designing this wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include another action method results to your Index view, you can call the `Html.Action` helper Method inside the `Index` View of MyBlog

```
@Html.Action("ShowRss ","Rss")
```

**EDIT :** *As per the comment*

If you do not want the `Layout`, Set the Layout property value as null in `ShowRss` view

```
@{
  Layout=null;
}
```

Comment: You should be using RenderAction, not Action (for performance reasons). Action is better used when you want to affect the rendered action before including it.

Comment: Is there a way to render the action without rendering it's layout?  It seems to include one layout inside of the other layout.

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to apply this to my login page which will need a layout when it's accessed directly, and no layout when it's just included.

Comment: you need to create a partial view which does not have the layout and include in both pages (home page and Login page)